# Player object loses Texture when placed on a List

Tags: c#, .net, xna, xna-4.0

I'm trying to store a series of GameObjects on a List. For some reason any time I put an object on the list, it loses it sprite reference (becomes null). All other object data (position, Color, etc) seems to stay in the object just fine. Here's what I've been trying:

```
static class Global
{
       public static List<GameObject> objects = new List<GameObject>();
}
```

This is the list I'm using. Now for the object in question - the player:

```
class Player : GameObject
{
    public Vector2 position = Vector2.Zero;
    public Texture2D sprite;
    public Color image_blend = Color.White;

    public Player() : base()
    { 
       //nothing here, nothing in base class either
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(sprite, position, image_blend);
    }
}
```

And finally in my main XNA class (important snippets):

```
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        sprPlayer = Content.Load<Texture2D>("player");

        player = new Player();
        player.sprite = sprPlayer;
        Global.objects.Add(player);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        for (int i = 0; i < Global.objects.Count; i++)
        {
            Global.objects[i].Draw(spriteBatch);

        }
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

I have a feeling I may be going about this the wrong way. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Player has a the Texture2D member called "sprite" not your GameObject class (which you didn't post the code for).

So when you create the Player class, you assign it's member the Texture2D, then you store the Player as it's parent GameObject making all of it's specific object type memebers inaccessible.

To fix, you'll want to make your base GameObject have the member "sprite" and not have on in your Player class that's inheriting from GameObject.

Comment: I think I found the problem. I did not declare the `Draw` and `Update` methods as `virtual` in `GameObject`, so they weren't being overriden by the Player class correctly. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your list `objects` is a `GameObject` list. I am guessing that any data in your `player` object that is not part of the `GameObject` class is being thrown out. I'm not sure though..

Also, you really should take a different approach for your sprite's textures. When you decide to add a bunch of entities of players and enemies and what not, each of those entities will have their own separate texture. If you decide to add 100 of these guys or so, you will have 100 duplicates of the same texture.

First I would recommend loading the texture into an array of textures.

```
//Please excuse my bugs, I haven't used c# in a while
//Place this in your global class:
public static Texture2D[] myTextures = new Texture2D[1]; //or more if you decide to load more.
//And place this in your LoadContent() Method:
Global.myTextures[0] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("player");
//Also, modify your player class:
public int textureIndex = 0;

public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(Global.myTextures[textureIndex], position, image_blend);
}
```

Now instead of each player object having it's own separate texture, It uses a texture from the array. Now you can have a lot of entities without unnecessary duplicate textures for each entity

Comment: Thanks for your help. It turns out that `GameObject` class needed it's functions declared as `virtual` for them to be correctly overriden by the `Player` class. I'm definitely going to use your method for the textures though. I had no idea they would be copied by each object.

Comment: They aren't copied by each object -- Content.Load<T>() always returns the same object instance, not a new copy each time it's called.  See the definition of ContenManager.Load() at MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197848.aspx